# removing multiple substrings fro a string in perl

Tags: perl

My script looks like below.

```
my $temp='abc.ifb "BATCHRANGE=110000198" def'; 
my $temp1=reverse $temp;    
my $temp2=substr($temp1,0,index($temp1,'"'));    
my $task=reverse $temp2;    
my $task1=substr($task,1);    
print "\n my task is $task1 \n";    
my $temp3 = '.ifb';
my $ifb = substr($temp, 0, index($temp, $temp3)+4);    
print "\n my ifb is $ifb \n";    
$temp =~ s/$ifb //;    
$temp =~ s/$task1 //;    
print "\n now temp is $temp \n";
```

Actually I want to capture three strings separately. But the final print is showing "BATCHRANGE=110000198" def. Whereas I am expecting "BATCHRANGE=110000198". What's wrong here?

Comment: You can split by `space`. Do you have any issues on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is that you have a space after `$task1` here: `s/$task1 //`.

A solution with regex:

```
my $temp='abc.ifb "BATCHRANGE=110000198" def'; 
my($ifb, $temp, $task);
if ($temp =~ m/^(.+\.ifb)\s+("[^"]*")\s+(.+)$/) {
    ($ifb, $temp, $task) = ($1, $2, $3);
    print "My ifb is '$ifb'\n";
    print "My temp is '$temp'\n";
    print "My task is '$task'\n";
}
else {
    print "Wrong format\n";
}
```

=>

```
My ifb is 'abc.ifb'
My temp is '"BATCHRANGE=110000198"'
My task is 'def'
```

Comment: Glad I could help! I edited my answer so that it also includes the exact problem in your script.

Comment: Thanks mate! great help :)

Comment: Better to use `if( $temp =~ m/..../ ) {` - e.g. assign `($ifb....) = ($1...)` only if the pattern matches...

Comment: This also works `my($ifb, $temp, $task)  = $temp =~ m/^(.+\.ifb)\s+("[^"]*")\s+(.+)$/;`

Comment: @jm666 Why not? I added the check for educational purposes. ;)

Comment: @mkHun Cool. Do you know in which version this was added?